# jQuery Toggle Hide All Others Click on Page Hides All

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to get the following to behave so that when one of the filter-name list items are clicked it shows the ul below it (all ul's with .filter-options are hidden by default) and hides any other ul list that is open.  Clicking again on the same filter-name list item would hide that ul as well. Also it would be brilliant if you clicked anywhere else that all of the ul's (.filter-options) would hide.

```
<ul class="all-filters" id="narrow-by-list">
    <li class="filter-name" id="Colour-filter">Colour
        <ul class="filter-options" id="Colour-options-list">
            <li>Black</li>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Green</li>
         </ul>
    <li>
    <li class="filter-name" id="Material-filter">Material
        <ul class="filter-options" id="Material-options-list">
            <li>Glass</li>
            <li>Wax</li>
            <li>Resin</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-name" id="Size-filter">Material
        <ul class="filter-options" id="Size-options-list">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my current jQuery that some what works...

```
jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#narrow-by-list .filter-name').click(function(event) {
          jQuery('ul.filter-options').not('> ul', this).hide("fast");
          jQuery('ul.filter-options', this).toggle("fast");
          event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You know your HTML is invalid right?

Comment: @j08691 nevermind, I just saw the way it was before the edit...

Comment: @j08691 sorry about that I rushed it a bit.  It isn't the exact code I'm using.  I just wanted to give a brief example showing the id's, classes, and structure. The HTML I'm using is/was properly structured and valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have html errors (you put open tags instead of close tags and forgot to close your ul's, that's mainly why nothing was working), here's the corrected version:

```
<ul class="all-filters" id="narrow-by-list">
<li class="filter-name" id="Colour-filter">Colour
    <ul class="filter-options" id="Colour-options-list">
        <li>Black</li>
        <li>Red</li>
        <li>Green</li></ul>
</li>
<li class="filter-name" id="Material-filter">Material
    <ul class="filter-options" id="Material-options-list">
        <li>Glass</li>
        <li>Wax</li>
        <li>Resin</li></ul>
</li>
<li class="filter-name" id="Size-filter">Material
    <ul class="filter-options" id="Size-options-list">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li></ul>
</li>
</ul>​
```

And here's the js that works:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#narrow-by-list .filter-name').click(function(event) {
    jQuery(this).find('ul.filter-options').toggle("fast").end().siblings().find('ul').hide('fast');
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});​
```

[Check out the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/V5CP2/). It finds the filter options within the this context, shows them, goes to its siblings and hides the list within them.

Comment: This doesn't allow the list to be closed by clicking on it's own heading...  Cheers for the effort though!

Comment: @TravelingAdMan That's an easy one. [See updated js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p7hHp/) and I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BAYPb/1/)

```
$("li.filter-name").on("click", function() {
    if ( $("ul", this).is(":visible") ) {
        $("ul", this).slideUp("fast");
    } else {
        $("li.filter-name ul").slideUp("fast");
        $("ul", this).slideDown("fast");
    }
});


$("body").on("click", function(e) {
    if ( !$(e.target).is("li") ) {
        $("li.filter-name ul").slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: This one works really well!  Is there a way to close up all of the lists if a user clicks outside of the li.filternames? Obviously it would have to exclude the ul that slides down.

Answer (score 0):

you have got some html missing declarations, i corrected them and changed your jQuery way:

[here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExU5S/10/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.filter-options').slideUp('fast');//hide all filters at the begining
    //you can use fast/slow or time declarations with miliseconds

    $('#narrow-by-list .filter-name').click(function() {
        $('.filter-options').slideUp(500);//hide all filters
        $(this).children('.filter-options').slideDown(500);//show clicked ele's filters
        //you can use other animations instead of slideUp/Down, like fadeIn() and fadeOut(), or pure hide() / show()
    });
});​
```

and note that $ === jQuery

html:

```
<ul class="all-filters" id="narrow-by-list">
    <li class="filter-name" id="Colour-filter">Colour
        <ul class="filter-options" id="Colour-options-list">
            <li>Black</li>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Green</li>
        </ul>
    <li>
    <li class="filter-name" id="Material-filter">Material
        <ul class="filter-options" id="Material-options-list">
            <li>Glass</li>
            <li>Wax</li>
            <li>Resin</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="filter-name" id="Size-filter">Numbers
        <ul class="filter-options" id="Size-options-list">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Comment: In my CSS the UL's are display: none; So I didn't need to hide them by default.  Your script also doesn't allow for the lists to be hidden by clicking on the initial list item of the same list that is showing.